# How to update the Firebase server in doze mode in android 11 or later

Tags: java, android, firebase, location, android-doze

I want to update the user location in doze mode I tried many things but as soon as the system enters the doze mode the location updates get off.

There is an answer to this question but this is not working in android 11
[Getting location updates when in doze mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254488/getting-location-updates-when-in-doze-mode)

Is there any solution by which I can update user location in doze mode